# Word boundary regex issue

Tags: r, regex, word-boundary

I'm having issues using word boundaries `\b` in my regular expression. I'm using R but the issue exists as well when I try http://regexr.com. The pattern I'm using is `\bs\.l\.\b`, and while I expected lines 1 and 3 below to match this pattern, only line 2 matches:

```
aaa s.l. bbb
aaa s.l.bbb
aaa s.l., bbb
```

See http://regexr.com/3f154 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) match in the following positions:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Now, you want to match `s.l.` that is preceded with a word boundary, and not followed with a word char. You need to replace the trailing `\b` with a `(?!\w)` lookaround:

```
\bs\.l\.(?!\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/etYch5/1)

Use `perl=TRUE` if you are using base R functions, and it will work as is in stringr functions powered with ICU regex library.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is not a word character, so there is no word boundary between the `.` characters and the space or comma.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't account for that.